# Apply formula to column then get the average

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out a way to realize the following function in excel:
In the picture below, I would like to for each value in col1, add it to all the values in col2, then save the average of the resulted values in the first cell in column result1. For example, adding the first value of 1 to every value in col2 gives 11, 21, 31, 41, 51. Then the average of 11, 21, 31, 41, 51 is 31, and it's saved in result1 column. Then adding the second value of 2 to every value in col2 gives 12, 22, 32, 42, 52. And the average is 32, and is saved in the second cell in column result1.

My question is how it can be done using formula to achieve this kind of functionality? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeju0.png You may need to confirm the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter (can't remember if needed for older versions of Excel).

Comment: `=(SUM(B$1:B$5)+A1*COUNT(B$1:B$5))/COUNT(B$1:B$5)` assumes this is in Columns A-C Starting rows 1

Comment: Or: `=AVERAGE(B$1:B$5)+A1`

Comment: @ScottCraner - lol sometimes all one needs is simple math.

Comment: If one has office 365 with dynamic formula: `=AVERAGE(B1:B5)+A1:A5` will spill the results autmatically.